# Site is going down time to time: how to get info from the HAProxy log?

Tags: logging, haproxy

I've started using HAProxy for a little while now, but still trying to get my head around with the logging. The site is going down time to time, mostly if accessed many times very quickly, saying:

**This site can’t be reached

unexpectedly closed the connection.**

on the browser and a lot of like these in the ha-proxy log:

```
haproxy[7938]: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:36601 [06/Apr/2019:17:49:12.485] fe_https be_https/localdfw 6/0/5 0 SD 0/0/0/0/0 0/0
haproxy[7941]: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:41143 [06/Apr/2019:17:49:12.490] fe_https be_https/localdfw 1/0/0 0 SD 0/0/0/0/0 0/0
```

I understand bits and pieces, like `SD` means 'the connection to the server died with an error during the data transfer' and `/0/0` before that probably means it's coming from the client side etc. but don't really understand why it's actually happening. Could anyone help me understanding the log or give me some pointer where should I look pls? Not sure if pasting the entire haproxy config would help or not but feel free to ask for any section you may want to have look. Thanks in advance!

-S

**==== This is the way it fails =====**

```
Apr  7 07:23:33 zenprdldfw01 haproxy[1989]: 5CE98076:D1CD_0A740205:01BB_5CA9A575_018B:07C5 xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:53709 [07/Apr/2019:07:23:33.730] fe_localdfw~ be_waf/zenprdlwaf01 112/0/0/30/142 200 1485/3331 - - ---- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 {www.zzzzzzzzzzz.com|||} "GET / HTTP/1.1"
Apr  7 07:23:33 zenprdldfw01 haproxy[1991]: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:53709 [07/Apr/2019:07:23:33.730] fe_https be_https/localdfw 1/0/171 3915 -- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0
Apr  7 07:23:33 zenprdldfw01 haproxy[1989]: 5CE98076:16D7_0A740205:01BB_5CA9A575_018C:07C5 xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5847 [07/Apr/2019:07:23:33.736] fe_localdfw~ be_waf/zenprdlwaf01 170/0/0/24/194 200 1485/3339 - - ---- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0 {www.zzzzzzzzzzz.com|||} "GET / HTTP/1.1"
Apr  7 07:23:33 zenprdldfw01 haproxy[1995]: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5847 [07/Apr/2019:07:23:33.736] fe_https be_https/localdfw 1/0/219 3923 -- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0
Apr  7 07:23:34 zenprdldfw01 haproxy[1989]: 5CE98076:4555_0A740205:01BB_5CA9A576_018D:07C5 xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:17749 [07/Apr/2019:07:23:34.074] fe_localdfw~ be_waf/zenprdlwaf01 110/0/0/18/128 200 1485/3343 - - ---- 2/2/0/0/0 0/0 {www.zzzzzzzzzzz.com|||} "GET / HTTP/1.1"
Apr  7 07:23:34 zenprdldfw01 haproxy[1994]: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:17749 [07/Apr/2019:07:23:34.067] fe_https be_https/localdfw 7/0/160 3927 -- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0
Apr  7 07:23:34 zenprdldfw01 haproxy[1989]: 5CE98076:68A2_0A740205:01BB_5CA9A576_018F:07C5 xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:26786 [07/Apr/2019:07:23:34.130] fe_localdfw~ be_waf/zenprdlwaf01 108/0/0/15/123 200 1485/3335 - - ---- 2/2/0/0/0 0/0 {www.zzzzzzzzzzz.com|||} "GET / HTTP/1.1"
Apr  7 07:23:34 zenprdldfw01 haproxy[1992]: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:26786 [07/Apr/2019:07:23:34.130] fe_https be_https/localdfw 1/0/152 3919 -- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0
Apr  7 07:23:34 zenprdldfw01 haproxy[1989]: 5CE98076:5F09_0A740205:01BB_5CA9A576_0190:07C5 xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:24329 [07/Apr/2019:07:23:34.184] fe_localdfw~ be_waf/zenprdlwaf01 108/0/0/19/127 200 1485/3343 - - ---- 2/2/0/0/0 0/0 {www.zzzzzzzzzzz.com|||} "GET / HTTP/1.1"
Apr  7 07:23:34 zenprdldfw01 haproxy[1993]: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:24329 [07/Apr/2019:07:23:34.184] fe_https be_https/localdfw 1/0/160 3927 -- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0
Apr  7 07:23:34 zenprdldfw01 haproxy[1989]: 5CE98076:A35F_0A740205:01BB_5CA9A576_0191:07C5 xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:41823 [07/Apr/2019:07:23:34.238] fe_localdfw~ be_waf/zenprdlwaf01 111/0/1/20/132 200 1485/3335 - - ---- 3/3/0/0/0 0/0 {www.zzzzzzzzzzz.com|||} "GET / HTTP/1.1"
Apr  7 07:23:34 zenprdldfw01 haproxy[1995]: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:41823 [07/Apr/2019:07:23:34.238] fe_https be_https/localdfw 1/0/152 3919 -- 1/1/1/1/0 0/0
Apr  7 07:23:34 zenprdldfw01 haproxy[1992]: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:43853 [07/Apr/2019:07:23:34.401] fe_https be_https/localdfw 1/0/0 0 SD 0/0/0/0/0 0/0
Apr  7 07:23:34 zenprdldfw01 haproxy[1989]: 5CE98076:B9BD_0A740205:01BB_5CA9A576_0192:07C5 xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:47549 [07/Apr/2019:07:23:34.287] fe_localdfw~ be_waf/zenprdlwaf01 109/0/0/21/130 200 1485/3333 - - ---- 2/2/0/0/0 0/0 {www.zzzzzzzzzzz.com|||} "GET / HTTP/1.1"
Apr  7 07:23:34 zenprdldfw01 haproxy[1990]: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:47549 [07/Apr/2019:07:23:34.287] fe_https be_https/localdfw 1/0/155 3917 -- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0
Apr  7 07:23:34 zenprdldfw01 haproxy[1991]: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:14862 [07/Apr/2019:07:23:34.454] fe_https be_https/localdfw 1/0/0 0 SD 0/0/0/0/0 0/0
Apr  7 07:23:34 zenprdldfw01 haproxy[1989]: 5CE98076:E213_0A740205:01BB_5CA9A576_0193:07C5 xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:57875 [07/Apr/2019:07:23:34.321] fe_localdfw~ be_waf/zenprdlwaf01 127/0/1/18/146 200 1485/3343 - - ---- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 {www.zzzzzzzzzzz.com|||} "GET / HTTP/1.1"
Apr  7 07:23:34 zenprdldfw01 haproxy[1995]: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:57875 [07/Apr/2019:07:23:34.321] fe_https be_https/localdfw 1/0/186 3927 -- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0
Apr  7 07:23:34 zenprdldfw01 haproxy[1989]: 5CE98076:CB0C_0A740205:01BB_5CA9A576_0194:07C5 xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:51980 [07/Apr/2019:07:23:34.350] fe_localdfw~ be_waf/zenprdlwaf01 157/0/0/18/175 200 1485/3341 - - ---- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0 {www.zzzzzzzzzzz.com|||} "GET / HTTP/1.1"
Apr  7 07:23:34 zenprdldfw01 haproxy[1994]: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:51980 [07/Apr/2019:07:23:34.350] fe_https be_https/localdfw 1/0/201 3954 -- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0
Apr  7 07:23:34 zenprdldfw01 haproxy[1990]: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27611 [07/Apr/2019:07:23:34.508] fe_https be_https/localdfw 45/0/44 0 SD 0/0/0/0/0 0/0
Apr  7 07:23:34 zenprdldfw01 haproxy[1991]: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:33155 [07/Apr/2019:07:23:34.672] fe_https be_https/localdfw 1/0/0 0 SD 0/0/0/0/0 0/0
Apr  7 07:23:34 zenprdldfw01 haproxy[1993]: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:49552 [07/Apr/2019:07:23:34.711] fe_https be_https/localdfw 7/0/6 0 SD 0/0/0/0/0 0/0
```

followed by a number of times like the last-line, until the site comes back up again.

Comment: Are you running HTTP mode?  If so, you need `option httplog` for better logging.  If not, why not?

Comment: yes, it's running in HTTP mode and the defaults section has that option set - wouldn't be applied to the front_end that served by localdfw as well? This is my logging format, FYI: `%ID\ %ci:%cp\ [%t]\ %ft\ %b/%s\ %Tq/%Tw/%Tc/%Tr/%Tt\ %ST\ %U/%B\ %CC\ %CS\ %tsc\ %ac/%fc/%bc/%sc/%rc\ %sq/%bq\ %hr\ %hs\ %{+Q}r`

Comment: Your log output doesn't seem to correspond to that format string.  It looks more like `option tcplog`.

Comment: I see something like this, when the site is working fine:
`Apr  7 06:46:54 zenprdldfw01 haproxy[1292]: 3F8F2AF7:EC9E_0A740205:01BB_5CA99CDE_78A3:050C xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:60574 [07/Apr/2019:06:46:54.554] fe_localdfw~ be_waf/zenprdlwaf01 76/0/0/30/106 200 420/999 - - ---- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0 {www.xxxxxxxxx.com||} "HEAD / HTTP/1.1"`

Comment: okay, I think I see a pattern: if I refresh the page press and holding the `Cmd + R` (on Mac), the site starts to fail exactly after 9 refreshes. I’ve added the section of the logs at the bottom of the original post. My _haproxy.cfg_ is here: https://pastebin.com/svDpxXxp FYI

Comment: Are you sure `tcp-request connection reject if { sc1_get_gpc0 gt 0 }` isn't the cause of this?

Comment: not sure. I'll try now commenting out that line and see if that solved the issue.

Comment: yes, both of these lines: `tcp-request   connection reject if { src_conn_rate ge 10 }` and `tcp-request   connection reject if { sc1_get_gpc0 gt 0 }` are cuasing the site to become unavailable but whatever the writings I've gone through about DDoS protection HAProxy are suggesting having them. What am I missing here?

Comment: Also, weren't those configurations supposed to block only the source that making multiple connection attempts rather than blocking the entier site?